# Description of the equalizer of $\prod _j R/I_j \rightrightarrows \prod _{i,j}R/(I_i+I_j)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes, intuition, geometric-intuition

This is a crosspost of [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602201/description-of-the-equalizer-of-prod-j-r-i-j-rightrightarrows-prod-i-jr?noredirect=1#comment3279407_1602201).

---

I have [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565916/sheafyness-and-relative-chinese-remainder-theorem) [several](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553900/multi-pullbacks-and-the-relative-chinese-remainder-theorem?lq=1) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553430/relative-chinese-remainder-theorem-and-the-lattice-of-ideals) in an attmept to get a general version of the Chinese remainder theorem without conditions on the ideals which will trivially imply the usual version if they are assumed comaximal.

The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597245/chinese-remainder-theorem-as-sheaf-condition/1601660#1601660) prompts me to ask what is the equalizer of the natural arrows below, sending $(r_j+I_j)_j$ to $(r_j+I_j+I_i)_{i,j}$ and $(r_i+I_i+I_j)_{i,j}$:
$$\prod _j R/I_j \rightrightarrows \prod _{i,j}R/(I_i+I_j)$$
The elegant example given there shows the equalizer is not generally $R/\bigcap_j I_j$, which was my naive geometric intuition. This can be rephrased as saying the closed pasting lemma does not hold for regular functions. I'm having trouble figuring out what *is* the equalizer. Unfortunately, I just don't have enough feel/knowledge/experience to figure it out.

**Update.** The comment by Steven Landsburg directs me to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21782/generalized-chinese-remainder-theorem) and the answer to it mentioning a paper by Kleinert. Although it is certainly related, I dont think it answers my question (apologies if I'm wrong). Maybe my initial phrasing was vague, so I'll try and clarify below.

I am *not* looking for conditions which guarantee $R/\bigcap_jI_i$ is the equalizer of the above arrows. Instead, I would like to understand *geometrically* what the general equalizer is, so that I can understand the geometric issues that arise when one looks at the sheaf condition for finite closed coverings. [Julian Rosen's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597245/chinese-remainder-theorem-as-sheaf-condition/1601660#1601660) hints tangent spaces may be involved. This is exactly along the lines of what I'm looking for - something like "the equalizer is comrpised of elements of $R/\bigcap _j I_j$ that satisfy some geometric conditions".

Comment: See the first answer  here:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21782/generalized-chinese-remainder-theorem.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg I edited the question to clarify what exactly I'm looking for. (I think) It's not quite the same as the answer you linked to.

Comment: As Julian already mentioned, the equalizer is the ring of families of sections on $V(I_i)$ which are compatible on the intersections $V(I_i) \cap V(I_j)$. I don't think that in general there is a different geometric description. (It is more interesting to find out when the sheaf condition is satisfied, i.e. the sections glue to a section on the union of the $V(I_i)$.)